# Can't select objects anymore

Tags: 3d-cursor

I seem to be stuck moving a '3d cursor' and can't find the way to return to the default object selection mode. Every time I click in the view, the cursor (picture down below) moves around and I can't select what I want.

[image: the cursor]

Is there a button to reset the view? If I reload my file, it remembers what I did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press T in 3d view for T-panel. Selection tool is first.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! (about same time than Magnus, thanks!, this is a further detailed answer)

Solution : press Spacebar-B or :press 'T' and go click up here (image).
Issue was : pressing spacebar-spacebar makes you go into 'cursor', when I wanted to be in 'Select box'
 [image]